# Moving object of fixed dimension without distortion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, spherical-geometry

I am trying to move a polygon object in a shapefile to a new location.  I will perform an offset so that the process can be automated by shifting the object to a new geographic coordinate or moved by some defined distance from the current position.  If the methods are different, let's focus on the shifting my rigid box to a new coordinate.

The object has defined dimensions (say 10m x 10m) but the reference coordinate system is a geographic coordinate system.  As such the dimensions change when I move it far from its current location.

Facts to consider in the solution:

- ArcPy solutions will work
- Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1
- A movement of the centroid would be acceptable, because it is the offset from the initial position that the object will be moved; alternatively it could be moved from any arbitrary point as long as the point is known
- The coordinate system is also arbitrary.  The solutions can specify or be general in that regard.
- The process needs to be repeated 100s of times

Comment: Since the object is represented by its corner parts, you could densify the shape (ie add more points to its perimeter) in an attempt to retain some semblance of its shape

Comment: Are you graphically moving the feature in an edit session?

Comment: @Paul I would like to use tools to automate this process.  For example it would be offset by x meters north and y meters east.  I'm updating the question to clarify this.

Comment: @DanPatterson I cannot see how adding more points would help.  The actual shape has hundreds of points and all of the distort in the same way.

Comment: From your description of a 10x10 feature, I didn't realize that you were referring to it's extent rectangle.

Comment: Shapes in geographic coordinates are going to distort when projected to a projected coordinate system - that's just the way it is. If you want a box (rectangle) or circle at the point then find the centre, project that and then make your box or circle in projected coordinates from the centre point. Or do your manipulation in geographic coordinates.

Comment: @PolyGeo The question was updated to incorporate you questions.  Let me know if I should further clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I understand that the distortion is natural when projecting a GCS into a PCS.  There is actually no problem with this.  What I want to do move a rigid 10x10 box (or any arbitrary shape) without losing its physical dimensions no mater where it is in the world.  I completely recognize that the visual representation on the screen will be distorted due to reprojections from a GCS to a PCS.  I don't care about maintaining the "squareness" in the projection; I care about maintaining my 10x10m box.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**The question asks for a rigid motion of the object on an idealization of the earth's surface.**  For ellipsoids the only continuous families of rigid motions possible are rotations around the earth's axis.  But for a spheroidal model there is a three-dimensional family of rigid motions and they can move an object from any location to any other (for two dimensions of motion) as well as rotate it about its center along the way (for the third dimension of motion).  To the extent a spheroid is sufficiently accurate for the purpose--and it will be in most applications--the task, then, is to accomplish such a motion.

**These motions are achieved by rotating the sphere.**  In general this is done by converting the object's vertices into earth-centered 3D coordinates, applying a 3 by 3 rotation matrix to them, and projecting the result (using any projection suitable for the destination).  This is fairly easy and it's fast, but it requires writing code to access and modify the vertex coordinates.

**With a GIS a general rotation can be performed without any such detailed coding.**  One method exploits the [Euler angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) representation of rotations.  For instance, we might specify the rotation in the Z-X-Z' convention: an arbitrary rotation can be achieved by a rotation around the Z axis (the Earth's polar axis), around the X axis (which extends from the center through the point at (lat,lon) = (0,0) where the Equator and Prime Meridian meet), and then again around the Z axis.

**To rotate around the Z axis,** use any cylindrical projection (including Plate Carree and Mercator, both of which are commonly used).  Create a new projection in which the amount of rotation is *subtracted* from all horizontal coordinates.  This can be accomplished by subtracting the amount of rotation from the reference meridian (as an angle) or from the false easting (as a distance).  (By making the scale at the Equator true, one degree of rotation is 1/360 of the length of the projected Equator.  Use this to convert from a rotation in degrees to a distance.)  Reproject the feature into this new projection, *but do not change its projection metadata.*  When the GIS displays the *new* feature using the *old* projection information, it will appear to have been rigidly rotated around the Z axis.

[image: Figure of Italy rotated around the Z axis]

*A polygonal feature representing Italy (in yellow) was rotated -40 degrees into the mid-Atlantic ocean (in purple) by reprojecting it from a standard Mercator projection into a Mercator projection in which 40 degrees was added to the central meridian.  The metadata for the reprojected shape still specify the original Mercator projection.*

**One way to rotate around the X axis** uses a Transverse Mercator projection (with central meridian at +-90 degrees, whichever best covers the feature).  Changing the false *Northing* in the projection metadata should do the trick.  A rotation around any axis lying in the Equatorial plane can be accomplished similarly.

After performing all three rotations make a reprojection, if necessary, into the final desired coordinate system.

**In summary,** any GIS feature can be rotated to occupy any desired position at any desired orientation by means of no more than four suitable reprojections (original to cylindrical to TM back to cylindrical to final) and perhaps with just one or two.

**Beware of complications** whenever the feature or any of its intermediate configurations straddles the +-180 degree meridian or either pole.  No GIS (that I know of) is capable of dealing correctly and transparently with all such situations (as many threads on this site attest).  Usually the solution (which is forced on us) is to split such features into portions that will not be subject to such complications and then re-assemble them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks.  Is this a process that can be scripted?  Let's say I need to repeat this process multiple times with offsets that are known, but different.